# Whenever I try run code it says runtime error.How can I fix it.(Hackerrank)

Tags: python, runtime, stdout, eoferror

I am new to here and Hackerrank.I am trying to solve simple array sum problem:

```
Given an array of integers, find the sum of its elements.

For example, if the array , , so return .

Function Description

Complete the simpleArraySum function in the editor below. It must return the sum of the array elements as an integer.

simpleArraySum has the following parameter(s):

ar: an array of integers
Input Format

The first line contains an integer, , denoting the size of the array.
The second line contains  space-separated integers representing the array's elements.

Constraints


Output Format

Print the sum of the array's elements as a single integer.
```

I am trying to find solution but I couldn't find the solution so far.It works on jupyter notebook.It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 34, in <module>
    result = simpleArraySum(ar)
  File "Solution.py", line 13, in simpleArraySum
    amount=int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

On output button it says 'no response on stdout'.Here is my code:

```
def simpleArraySum(ar):
    #
    # Write your code here.
    #
    amount=int(input())

    nums=list(map(int,input().split()))

    sums=0

    for i in nums:

        sums+=i

    print(sums)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way;

```
def sum_array(arr):
    total = 0
    for i in arr:
        total += i
    return total
```

There are some issues with your code.

- You want an array to be passed to function but you also want user to input values.
- You cast input to integer but after that you split input.

Note that there are many to solve this problem without writing your own custom function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine. Just copy this code and paste and you're ready to go:

```
def simpleArraySum(ar):
    #
    # Write your code here.
    #
    sums=0
    for i in nums:
        sums+=i
    return sums

amount = int(input())
nums = list(map(int,input().split()))
print(simpleArraySum(nums))
```

I didn't do anything, I just read the input outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

This Should work fine with you :

```
amount=int(input())
nums=list(map(int,input().split()))
sums=0
for i in nums:
    sums+=i
print(sums)
```

Issue that you have only one problem :

 **1.** You just need to sum all elements of given array , **Just sum** , you don't need to read input from User.That's what i changed in your code , then remove everything and write code after i modified and should work and Everything will be fine.